# unhandled win32 exception occurred in git.exe

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to clone a specific repository from Bit Bucket to my local using Git I am encountering an error like this. But it only happens for the specif repo. All other works fine. Even I checked with my team mates for them no issue for that. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please post some image or command you used.

Comment: I used git clone bitbucket repository link